# ImportError: No module named HT16K33

Tags: gpio, python

When I am importing a library (specifically Adafruit_LED_Backpack using Python3) I get the error

ImportError: No module named HT16K33

How do I install that library?

EDIT: when using Python 2.7, the reported error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", 
line 1, in <module> File "Adafruit_LED_Backpack/Matrix8x8.py", 
line 31, in init super(Matrix8x8, self).__init__(**kwargs) File "Adafruit_LED_Backpack/HT16K33.py", 
line 46, in init self._device = i2c.get_i2c_device(address, **kwargs) 
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", 
line 66, in get_i2c_device 
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", 
line 95, in init IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

–

Comment: Have you tried this https://learn.adafruit.com/led-backpack-displays-on-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/usage

Comment: I was attempting to use python3 for that tutorial, and it worked up until then.

Comment: that may be the problem. It may not support python3. or it may not be installed for python3, Can you try it with python 2.7?

Comment: Using python 2.7, I got:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Adafruit_LED_Backpack/Matrix8x8.py", line 31, in __init__
    super(Matrix8x8, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "Adafruit_LED_Backpack/HT16K33.py", line 46, in __init__
    self._device = i2c.get_i2c_device(address, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 66, in get_i2c_device
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 95, in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory